# How to get first seconds of the next day based on current seconds?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have to convert seconds in UTC into day then add interval of one day and return seconds in UTC.

Here is what I have:

**option #1**

```
public static final long nextDayStartSec(long epochSecondsInUTC) {
    return (epochSecondsInUTC / TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1) + 1) * TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1);
}
```

But not all days contain 86400 seconds according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> Modern Unix time is based on UTC, which counts time using SI seconds,
>   and breaks up the span of time into days almost always 86400 seconds
>   long, but due to leap seconds occasionally 86401 seconds.

**option #2**

```
public static final long nextDayStartSec(long epochSecondsInUTC) {
    return DateUtils.addMilliseconds(DateUtils.round(new Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(epochSecondsInUTC)), Calendar.DATE), -1)
            .toInstant().atZone(systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

But it uses wide range of libraries (including [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/)) and hard to read.

Is there something simple that I missed?

Comment: Unix time is ignorant of leap seconds, but not UTC. So the given answer of @assylias is quite satisfying as long as you - as most users - wish to ignore this exotic feature. Do you else want to see an answer related to leap seconds?

Comment: And I strongly suspect that your input "epochSecondsInUTC" is really not an UTC-input counting leap seconds but rather UNIX-based counting non-leap-seconds since 1970-01-01T00Z. So my conclusion and advise is to just accept the answer of @assylias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Java 8, the new time API allows you to write it this way (it adds one day to the given instant):

```
public static final long nextDayStartSec(long epochSecondsInUTC) {
  OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecondsInUTC).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  return odt.plusDays(1).toEpochSecond();
}
```

If you want to get the instant of the start of the next day, it could look like this:

```
public static final long nextDayStartSec(long epochSecondsInUTC) {
  OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecondsInUTC).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  return odt.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond();
}
```

Comment: No need to do `OffsetDateTime.of(dateTime, ZoneOffset.UTC)`. Instead just call `dateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. The "at" methods are all designed to flow nicely.In this case, you can even call `date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond()`.